# How can I prove that a functional is within the dual space of H1 space?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

[image]

My understanding of a dual space is that it is a space of all the linear bounded operators that transform objects in Sobolev space (for this case) to the real or complex spaces. I am not sure if this is complete or even correct. Also, I don't really get what the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality has to do with this.

Comment: It is clearly linear, you just need to show that it is bounded.

Comment: First use Cauchy-Schwarz and then $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}\le\|\cdot\|_{V}$.

Comment: @amsmath what does this mean " then ∥⋅∥L2≤∥⋅∥V." ?  I understand that the functional is on the LHS and by this inequality I prove that it is bounded but what is the RHS?

Comment: can anyone elaborate further on this please? I don't have a background in pure math since I am an engineering grad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to know a little bit about [Sobolev space theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space), the definition of $H^1$ and its norm.
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$| \ell(v)| \leq \left( \int_{\Omega} |f|^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{\Omega} |v|^2 dx \right)^{1/2} = ||f||_2 ||v||_2 \leq ||f||_2 ( ||v||_2 + C||Dv||_2)=  ||f||_2 K||v||_{V}.$$

Then, by definition of [operator norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)
$$   || \ell|| \leq K||f||_2    $$

Comment: thanks a lot. but what are C, D and K and why do we expand ||v||2. does this have to do with the fact that its 1st derivative is square integrable? or do they signify the linear operations  in the dual space ?

Comment: $C$ is a constant, $D$ stands for the derivative operator and $K$ is also a constant. adding the norm of the derivative is possible just by defining the Sobolev space $H^1$, the first order derivatives are in $L^2$, as you said yourself. There is a link above about an operator's standard, or if you prefer you can search for more details.